# Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array Python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

It is a Leetcode question (Leetcode 26), which is Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array.

Given an integer array nums sorted in non-decreasing order, remove the duplicates in-place such that each unique element appears only once. The relative order of the elements should be kept the same. Then return the number of unique elements in nums.

Consider the number of unique elements of nums to be k, to get accepted, you need to do the following things:

- Change the array nums such that the first k elements of nums contain the unique elements in the order they were present in nums initially. The remaining elements of nums are not important as well as the size of nums.
- Return k.

My code is as follows:

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        new_nums = []
        for item in nums:
            if item not in new_nums:
                new_nums.append(item)
        nums = new_nums
        return len(new_nums)
```

Output from Leetcode is like this:
[leetcode_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvXu1.png)

However, I have tried my code locally and got the correct answer as shown in the image below:
[my_code_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i9ib.png)

I am not sure what the problem is and why I am not able to get the correct answer in Leetcode.

Comment: Do you need to check `item not in new_nums` or maybe only `item != new_nums[-1]`? :)

Comment: @Antoine I have just tried item != new_nums[-1], the result seems to be the same, it outputs [1,1] instead of [1,2]. When I run locally as shown in the image above (i.e. my_code_screenshot), I can get [1,2] but I don't know why I am getting [1,1] in leetcode

Comment: Can you show the actual code? (simply replacing the if condition with `item != new_nums[-1]` should result in an error (index out of range).

Comment: @Antoine Sure, please find the screenshot here: https://entuedu-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/hding002_e_ntu_edu_sg/EWsq0mo7UFFDkY-S_VdcEEIBq6dyiaIU57aIeusafmHatw?e=hu1f7j, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this program:

```
def f(nums: list[int]):
    nums = [1, 2, 3]


aa = [0]
f(aa)
print(aa)
```

It outputs `[0]`. In the moment you say `nums = ...` inside the function, `nums` becomes local. So you are only allowed to change the list (for example, by saying `nums[i] = ...` etc.) but not define it again.

My comment above `not in nums --> != nums[-1]` refers only to the efficiency of the code.

Comment: I would say even before `nums = ...`, the moment you define `nums` as the parameter, it becomes local to `f`. I mean `nums` is already local, the object that `nums` refers to is the same object that the other name in global (here `aa`) refers.

Comment: @Antoine Thank you very much for the explanation and comment! So can I say that for parameters for a function, we can only change or modify the input argument (in this case is nums), and we cannot let it be equal to something else (in this case like nums = new_nums)

Answer (score 0):

Although the line `nums = new_nums` is redundant, your answer is correct.

If you use Python 3.7 and above(dictionaries maintain the insertion order) you could simply do:

```py
lst = list("aabccdeffgg")
print(len(dict.fromkeys(lst)))
```

Comment: The answer is not correct (according to leet code), since the problem demands changing the array that `nums` refers to.

Comment: @Antoine I was introducing them to use a dictionary to solve the duplication part. Mutating the actual parameter is not hard. It can simply be done with `nums[:] = list(dict.fromkeys(nums))` for example.

Comment: @S.B Thank you for the explanation! If let's say for example, the original input (nums) is [1,1,2,2], and we want nums to become [1,2] in the end (remove duplicates), does nums[:]=... applies? (the problem wants us to change the actual parameter nums)

Comment: @Carina yes exactly

Comment: @S.B That (`nums[:] = ...`) is a nifty trick :)

Comment: @Antoine S.B and Antoine, Thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: @Carina You're welcome. You can mark one of the answers by hitting on the check mark.